# How to open a process and make the steam read/writers available for the entire class

Tags: c#, process, stream, console

I am currently writing an application that manipulates an existing Console app that has already been built. Currently I am able to launch the existing application and then write to the console and receive the output. But I need my app to basically keep the console app running behind the scenes and keep the app open and ready to write a new command to the window to receive more information back. Below is the current code I am using. I am wondering if there is  a way to call this code on launch to start the console application.

**Code**:

```
   private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string ApplicationPath = "python";
        string ApplicationArguments = "Console/dummy.py";
        string returnValue;

        //Process PyObj = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo PyObjStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

        PyObjStartInfo.FileName = ApplicationPath;
        PyObjStartInfo.Arguments = ApplicationArguments;
        PyObjStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        PyObjStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        PyObjStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        //PyObjStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        //PyObj.StartInfo = PyObjStartInfo;

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        using (Process process = Process.Start(PyObjStartInfo))
        {
            StreamWriter sw = process.StandardInput;
            StreamReader sr = process.StandardOutput;

            if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("auth");
            }
            sw.Close();
            sw.Close();
            returnValue = sr.ReadToEnd();
            MessageBox.Show(returnValue.ToString());
        }
        //Thread.Sleep(5000);
        //PyObj.WaitForExit();
        //PyObj.Close();
    }
```

As you can see this utilizes a button click currently, but I would like the code to run off the bat as soon as my application starts up. Then keep the console app running and in memory so that I can interact with it. Is there any way to do this in C#.net?

For reference. The console application I cam calling is blank and just returns dummy answers for the time being.. here is the Python code below.

**python code**:

```
  import os, pprint

def main():
    keepGoing = True
    while keepGoing:
      response = menu()
      if response == "0":
          keepGoing = False
      elif response == "auth":
          print StartAuthProcess()
      elif response == "verify":
          print VerifyKey(raw_input(""))
      elif response == "get":
          print Info()
      else:
          print "I don't know what you want to do..."

def menu():
    '''
    print "MENU"
    print "0) Quit"
    print "1) Start Autentication Process"
    print "2) Verify Key"
    print "3) Get Output"

    return raw_input("What would you like to do? ")
    '''
    return raw_input();
def StartAuthProcess():
    return 1;

def VerifyKey(key):
    if(key):
        return 1;
    else:
        return 0;

def Info():
    info = "{dummy:stuff}";
    return info;

main()
```

Comment: Can you not just start the process and leave it running? (Also, I removed the wpf tag, since nothing in the question is related to WPF.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few places you can put code that will run right away. First of all, you'll see a Program.cs that has your `static void Main` function. That is where your application starts executing. The Form isn't even shown until the call to `Application.Run()`. This is a good place to put very early initialization stuff.

If you want things to happen when your Form is first opened, you can override the virtual [`Form.OnShown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onshown.aspx) method:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e) {
    base.OwnShown(e);

    // Call whatever functions you want here.
}
```

Note that you really shouldn't use any blocking calls like `Sleep` in the GUI thread (aka your button click handler). This will cause your GUI to hang, and feel unresponsive. I'm not sure exactly how you plan on interacting with the background process (will it be automatic, or user-driven?) But any blocking calls (namely reads from stdout) should happen on a background thread. You can then use `Control.Invoke` to marshal calls back onto the UI thread to update controls, etc.